# Capture Video from Public Web Video Feed

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, vlc, mpeg

I've unsuccessfully mucked around with this on my own and need help.

Given the public Web camera feed at https://itsvideo.arlingtonva.us:8011/live/cam58.stream/playlist.m3u8 I'd like to be able to be able to capture the video feed into an MP4 or MPG file with a reasonably accurate timestamp using the Windows command line (so I can put it into a batch script, etc.).

This is probably easy for someone who is already a wiz with VLC or FFmpeg or some such tool.

Additional wish list items would be to call up a higher resolution stream for a shorter duration (so as to balance I/O impact) and/or to just get still images instead of the video offered.

For instance, the m3u file has the following parameters:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=214105,CODECS="avc1.100.40",RESOLUTION=352x288
chunklist_w977413411.m3u8
```

Would there be a way to substitute any of these to increase the resolution and reduce the video duration in a corresponding way so that net I/O is the same? Or even to just get a still image, whether higher res or not?

Comment: You can just copy it: `ffmpeg -i feed -c copy out.ts`. You can directly save to MP4 but if the process is killed, output will be unplayable unless repaired.

Comment: Mulvya: Perfect! So simple ... it worked the first time, and though it did terminate after 78 seconds, the resulting MP4 did not need repair.